# Latex Figures appear before text in pandoc markdown

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I am using pandoc to convert markdown to pdf, but I need to place some figures with more formating than the

```
  ![Alt text](image.png)
```

so I use something like this:

```
  # Document with figures

  This document have figures but they appear before the title

  \begin{figure}
  \centering
  {\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{some_figure.png}}
  \caption{Comparing Dq from different p-model}
  \end{figure}
```

and then I use the following command:

```
 pandoc -H test_fig.sty test_fig.md -o test_fig.pdf
```

and test_fig.sty have:

```
 \usepackage{graphicx}
```

the resulting pdf have first the figure and then the title.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is most likely because the `figure` environment floats, which is not what you're after. For this you have a couple of options:

1. Add the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) which provides the `H` float specifier, allowing you to use

   ```
   \usepackage{float}% http://ctan.org/pkg/float
   %...

   \begin{figure}[H]
   %...
   \caption[<ToC>]{<regular>}
   \end{figure}
   ```

   stopping the float from moving around.
2. Add the [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) (or the super-tiny [`capt-of`](http://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of)) package and wrap your figure inside a `minipage` to keep the image and caption together. Use it as follows:

   ```
   \usepackage{caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/caption
   %\usepackage{capt-of}% http://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of
   %...

   \noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
   %...
   \captionof{figure}[<ToC>]{<regular>}
   \end{minipage}
   %...
   ```

For more information on the placement of figures, see [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764) and [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275/5764).

The above proposals are purely LaTeX-driven.

---

If you want to manage this within pandoc, consider adding the following to a file called `float_adjustment.tex` and place it in your project folder:

```
\usepackage{float}
\floatplacement{figure}{H}
```

Then include this file as part of your preamble using the pandoc header

```
---
title: "A title"
author: "An author"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B %Y')`"
output:
  rmarkdown::pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes        
    includes:  
      in_header: figure_placement.tex
---
```

All figures should be forced in-place via the `[H]`ERE float specification.

Comment: +1 for `\floatplacement{figure}{...}`. I have a customised template for using with pandoc, and couldn't figure out how to set the default float placement to `{!htbp}` - setting it with `\floatplacement` does the trick.

Comment: Same! I'm using pandoc and `\floatplacement{figure}{H}` in a custom template prevents images from floating to top of the page.

Answer (score 22):

A simple solution is to add a line with a **backslash and space** immediately after the figure, followed by a blank line:

```
![Alt text](image.png)
\ 

Some text after the figure...
```

Do not forget the space after the backslash!
This seems to work on Pandoc 1.12.4.2.

Edit: as pointed out in the comments, this will suppress figure captions.

Comment: Worked for me, nice tips for little projects (reports, articles) without to have to override templates. Thanks

Comment: I like this one too - but am curious as to what that backslash does?

Comment: In Pandoc Markdown, a backslash followed by a newline generates a hard line break. The tex file will have an inline image (no figure environment) followed by a hard line break. The image will be without caption. The same can be achieved with spaces add the and of the line (after the image) and then no empty lines before the next paragraph.

Answer (score 10):

I don't like the solution to use a 2-step compilation (Latex -> sed -> pdf).

You can overwrite the **figure** environment in your Latex template:

```
% Overwrite \begin{figure}[htbp] with \begin{figure}[H]
\usepackage{float}
\let\origfigure=\figure
\let\endorigfigure=\endfigure
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][]{%
  \origfigure[H]
}{%
  \endorigfigure
}
```

In this way you can still use the direct pdf generation.

Comment: Probably the better solution for me. No sed, only a include in header to append to the command line. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Pandoc generates tex output with all of the tables and figures defined with the `[htbp]` placement options.  This isn't a massive problem though, since you can use sed to change all instances of `[htbp]` to `[H]` e.g.

```
sed -i 's/begin{figure}\[htbp\]/begin{figure}\[H\]/g' tex/out.tex
```

Basically, just use pandoc to generate the tex output, then run your tex engine afterwards (twice) and you'll be good to go.  You'll also need to make sure that the `float` package is actually being used in your template file (which contains your tex preamble):

```
\usepackge{float}
```

NOTE: Although in the default latex template, the `float` package is used, but it's only used if you're actually using tables:

```
$if(tables)$
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{float}
$endif$
```

...I just moved `\usepackage{float}` to the line outside of the if block in my custom template.

Comment: Do you mean `s/begin{figure}\[[htbp]*\]/begin{figure}[H]/g` ?

Comment: Nope, the square brackets in this case are literal and not a regex character grouping; `[htbp]` should become `[H]`.

Comment: Wouldn't the `\[[htbp]\]' be more robust? It would work for placement involving _any_ subset of `htbp`. (BTW I use `sed` a lot. I wasn't aware of the`-i` flag. Useful that.)

Comment: Sure it will be more robust - in case pandoc changes the way it writes figures in the future.  For now, probably not needed, but do whatever makes you happy.  :-)